# Getting rid of duplicates with arrayHash

Tags: java, hash

I need to implement a hashing algorithm where the collision handling is done via linear probing. I know that by definition the hash table won’t store duplicates.I am not allowed to pre-process the word list file to eliminate duplicates first and then try to load the words into the hash table. My class arrayHashWithLinearProbing() is soppose to handle this part. Below is my class and some other information to help understand what I am doing. (Note: I am reading from a text file) I need help so that the hash table will not store duplicates.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class HashWithLinearProbing {
   int tableSize = 423697;
   BigInteger ts = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(tableSize));
   Hash[] hashTable;
   public HashWithLinearProbing() {
       hashTable = new Hash[tableSize];
       for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
          hashTable[i] = new Hash();
       }
}

public int hashVal(String p) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
        s = s + (int) p.charAt(i);
    }
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s);
    BigInteger k = bi.remainder(ts);
    int j = k.intValue();
    return j;
}

public void arrayHashWithLinearProbing(String s) {
    // you will implement a hash table using the hashVal() method described
    // above.
    // Linear probing will use the "next" field to chain all the values that
    // have collisions.
    // this method will store String s at a linearly probed location
    // starting from hashVal(s) in the table
    // if s is not already i the table. Essentially, you will not have any
    // duplicates.
    int hashIndex = hashVal(s);
    int previousI = -1;
    int i = hashIndex;

    // Find the next slot
    do {
        if (hashTable[i].val.isEmpty()) {
            hashTable[i].val = s;
            break;
        }
        Hash hash = hashTable[i];
        if (hash.val.equals(s)) {
            hash.val = s;
            break;
        }
        previousI = i;
        i = (i + 1) % tableSize;
        hashTable[previousI].next = i;
    } while (i != hashIndex);
}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Comment: You have some pretty instructive comments in the code already, please try to attempt the problem yourself and then ask on specific questions you have. We're here to help you learn, but not to provide code for you.

Comment: sorry i did not mean to come off as that way!

Comment: When does your program break? What inputs cause the hash table to store a duplicate? Why do you think that happens?

Comment: turns out there was nothing wrong with with the arrayprobing class and my problem was coming from another class haha